# Как создать группу объектов, зависящих от родительского, которые будут вращаться?

Tags: c++, opengl

С помощью OpenGL в С++ я создал стилизованное изображение самолета с двумя моторами (вид спереди) и создал пропеллер с помощью `glutSolidSphere` (центр) и с помощью `GL_POLYGON` сами лопасти.

Нужно, чтобы по нажатию клавиши 1 он вращался (центр и лопасти). я так понимаю через команду `glRotate` как-то задать вращение. но как создать группу объектов, зависящих от родительского, которые и будет выполнять `glRotate`? Как сам код написать - понятия не имею..

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю примерно такой псевдокод:

```
void DrawCenter() {
  gluSolidSphere(...);
}

void DrawLopasti() {
  for (int i = 0; i < LopastiNum; ++i) {
    glBegin(GL_POLIGON);
    ....
    glEnd();
  }
}

void DrawPropeller() {
  glPushMatrix();
  glRotatef(...);
  DrawCenter();
  DrawLopasti();
  glPopMatrix();
}
```

В идеале все объекты сцены имеет смысл представить в виде древовидной структуры в программе и позиционировать подобъекты относительно координат своего родителя.